# Sencha touch: Issues with creating my first application using the CMD in windows 7

Tags: mobile, extjs, cmd

I read a [good-for-a-start post](http://senchatouchdev.com/wordpress/2013/03/04/sencha-touch-2-1-1-getting-started/).

Then according to the author of the above post, I decided to get the requirements for Sencha mobile development: Sencha touch 2.1.1 GPL/commercial download, the SenchaCMD v4.0.2.67 which I have installed.

I have copied the Sencha touch-2.1.1 to the htdocs folder inside the xampp folder. So in other words, I don't need the SDK or anything else for now. I have also updated the `PATH` variable.

When I type this command: `sencha generate app Helloworlds ..\Helloworlds`, I get this output with errors:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\senchaTouch> sencha generate app MyApp1 ../MyApp1

Sencha Cmd v4.0.2.67

[ERR] Unable to locate 'framework.dir' property from sencha.cfg

[ERR] Please ensure this command was executed from a valid framework directory

[ERR] Non-framework directory
```

So what should I do about this framework issue? And where is this `framework.dir`?

I tried to add the path of the installed SenchaCMD on it but this is what happened:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\senchaTouch>sencha generate app Helloworld2 ..\C:\Users\Adrian\b
in\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.2.67\HelloWorld2
```

I obtain this output:

```
Sencha Cmd v4.0.2.67
[ERR] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

I am confused. Where is the problem exactly?

Comment: WHy are you using Touch 2.1.1? The latest version is 2.3.1 - give that a shot first.

Answer (score 0):

May be its  late. But Here is the link which provides step by step tutorial for developing your first Sencha Touch application and deploy it to Android.

mobiletechtutorials.blogspot.in